# Uploading files from .exe to server

Tags: vb.net, winforms, upload

I wanted to know how I would be able to upload files to my server from my WinForms .exe application. I tried: `My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(myFile, myServer)` but I get this error 'The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.' Anyone know another way of uploading files to my server from a .exe? Thanks.

I'm using VB and .Net Framework 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way, but it sounds like you are uploading to the wrong page (HTTP error = **404**).  **Check your URL**.

```
Dim fileName As String = AskUserForFileName()
Dim web As New WebClient()
web.UploadFile(uriString, fileName)
```

Comment: Ahh, yeah, I thought so. I have made a FileUpload on Web browser in asp.net and it works fine, I looked at the path that I upload it to, and when I try the path in the Windows forms, it gives me this error. Thanks

Comment: I don't think that's right, but if you look in the html <form> element, that will probably point you in the right direction.

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment correctly, or I just don't understand your reply comment =], What I mean, is that when I upload from my web site, it works fine, but when I try uploading from the .exe it just doesn't work, I get the error stated above. Like you said, it might be the path, so I checked the path that I use in asp.net file upload, and used that path for my .exe file path. Thanks.

Comment: Does the .exe need to be on the server? As I am trying to upload to the server while the .exe isn't uploaded to my server. Just wanted to check that one. Thanks again.